# Special character in Android TextView stopped working in the app after almost a year?

Tags: android, csv, special-characters, simplecursoradapter

7 months ago I built an app targeting Android 2.3.3 and above (API 10). In the app I use an **SimpleCursorAdapter** which is [deprecated now](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html). First the app reads a .csv document and saves the information in the SQLiteDatabase.

The **SimpleCursorAdapter** gets the info out of the database and shows a list on the screen. The .csv has a few words with the special character **ë** in it, example: variëteit. The app build 7 months ago that is now in the store works fine and shows the special character correct in the list.

Here is the problem:
When I build the app now on my phone it doesn't show the special character **ë** in the list but this instead:

[image]

When I download the 7 months old version from the store, it does show the correct special character.

The weird thing is, I didn't change the code! So I have no idea why it suddenly stopped working. Does anyone have an idea?

*What did I try:*
I tried to change the encoding to: ISO8859-1, but that also gave a weird character..

I tried: String correctText = Html.fromHtml(textView.getText().toString()));
But that also didn't work.

EDIT:
The problem is reading the .csv file. When I put the value in the database it is already incorrect. I tried reading the .csv file with different encodings, but I coulnd't get the right encoding... I tried all the standard encodings. But it still didn't work. I can't find out what the right encoding is...

Comment: Looks like a typical character encoding issue. Does the string come from a server? Was the character encoding probably changed there?

Comment: No the string comes out of the database. The database is filled with information that is in a .csv I believe it is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Maybe the CSV file uses a different encoding than UTF-8.

Comment: Yeah it is, I tried to load the document in a lot of other encodings... But it didn't work.

Comment: I fixed it! I copied the .csv to a new UTF-8 encoded file, and it did work! This time I copied it with Notepad++, that did work. I already tried it using Excel 2016, but that didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I checked the details of the file it told me it was UTF-8 encoded.

I created an new file with Notepadd++, before I created that file I made sure Notepad++ had these settings: (Settings > Preferences... >)

[image]

I copied and pasted the content to this new file.
Then it worked because the file was for sure good encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the encoding in Android Studio?

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks, I built the app in every encoding, but it doesn't change something...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16687239)

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ How can you insert an image in a comment?